# How to get the rows of a dataframe from columns between two other columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want the columns of a dataframe between two indices, `endDate` and `totalCurrentAssets` but excluding them. So I tried with `.iloc`:

```
>>>ticker.balance_sheet().loc[:, 'endDate':'totalCurrentAssets']

        endDate     cash    shortTermInvestments    netReceivables  inventory   otherCurrentAssets  totalCurrentAssets
symbol  row                             
MSFT    0   2019-06-30  11356000000     122476000000    29524000000     2063000000  10133000000     175552000000
1   2018-06-30  11946000000     121718000000    26481000000     2662000000  6855000000  169662000000
2   2017-06-30  7663000000  125238000000    22431000000     2181000000  5183000000  162696000000
3   2016-06-30  6510000000  106531000000    18277000000     2251000000  6091000000  139660000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to chain `loc` with an `iloc` to take a further slice:

```
df.loc[:,'endDate':'totalCurrentAssets'].iloc[:,1:-1]
```

Or you could also use `Index.get_loc`:

```
cols = df.columns
df.iloc[:, cols.get_loc('endDate')+1 : cols.get_loc('totalCurrentAssets')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Start from retrieving **integer** indices (numbers) of the columns in question:

```
n1 = df.columns.get_loc('endDate')
n2 = df.columns.get_loc('totalCurrentAssets')
```

Then use *iloc* with these indices, respectively corrected:

```
df.iloc[:, n1 + 1 : n2]
```

This time column with integer number *n2* will **not** be retrieved.